# One Route cannot be opened multiple times in my Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, routes

I am working on a Flutter app that has multiple routes (pages). I can open all the pages properly one time, but if I try to open the same page multiple times it doesn't work (page doesn't open). Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'page1.dart';
import 'page2.dart';
import 'page3.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Learning Flutter',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> contentList = [
      'Open page 1',
      'Open page 2',
      'Open page 3',
    ];

List<Route> myRoute = [
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page1()),
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page2()),
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => Page3()),
];

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Learning Flutter'),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: contentList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(contentList[index]),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(myRoute[index]);
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

Below messages retrieved from the console:

> Exception caught by gesture
>
> The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture: Cannot
> install a MaterialPageRoute after disposing it.
> 'package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart': Failed assertion: line 199
> pos 12: '!_transitionCompleter.isCompleted'
>
> Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we
> should provide substantially more information in this error message to
> help you determine and fix the underlying cause. In either case,
> please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md
>
> When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
> #2      TransitionRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:199:12)
> #3      ModalRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:1094:11)
> #4      _RouteEntry.handlePush (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2989:11)
> #5      NavigatorState._flushHistoryUpdates (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:3937:17)
> #6      NavigatorState._pushEntry (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:4526:5)
>
> ...
>
> Handler: "onTap" Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#a2553   debugOwner:
> GestureDetector   state: ready   won arena   finalPosition:
> Offset(183.1, 121.0)   finalLocalPosition: Offset(179.1, 23.9)
> button: 1   sent tap down

Have I made any mistakes in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Using 'named routes' solved my issue. Courtesy to the answer posted here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766770/how-to-navigate-to-next-page-in-dynamic-list-view-flutter].[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59766770/how-to-navigate-to-next-page-in-dynamic-list-view-flutter)

I am sharing the complete code is below (if someone someday encounters the same issue this might help them out).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'page1.dart';
import 'page2.dart';
import 'page3.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Learning Flutter',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(),
        '/page1': (context) => Page1(),
        '/page2': (context) => Page2(),
        '/page3': (context) => Page3(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> contentList = [
      'Open page 1',
      'Open page 2',
      'Open page 3',
    ];

final myRoute = [
  'page1',
  'page2',
  'page3',
];

return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Learning Flutter'),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: contentList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(contentList[index]),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/${myRoute[index]}');
          },
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```